# Столбец даты в dataframe записан в tuple типе, нужно перевести его в DateTime Index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Имеется dataframe с двумя столбцами (дата и показатель). Но столбец даты записан в tuple типе, нужно перевести его в DateTime Index. Получал я этот столбец(date) из базы данных postgreSQL в varchar виде с помощью запросов. Я попытался получить дату в тип date, но вывод был некорректный[image: Мой dataframe]
Используемые библиотеки: pandas, numpy

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Пример данных в вопросе должен быть в воспроизводимом виде. Иначе вопрос будет закрыт.

Comment: Ну попробуйте так как-то что ли для начала, если там и правда кортежи `df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x[0])` Ну и `pd.to_datetime`, если строку надо в дату перевести.